# Duplicate [tag:platformer] [tag:platform-game]

Tags: discussion

Are the tags [platformer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platformer) and [platform-games](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platform-games) duplicates? If not, what's supposed to be the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the platform-games tag description is better written, but clearly the question counts (132 for platformer vs. 46 for platform-games) imply that platformer is the more intuitive usage. Platformer sounds a little informal, but it would be the first noun I'd think of when asked.

So I'd suggest moving the platform-games description over to platformer and merging the two tags.

Comment: I've combined the descriptions and merged the tags.

Comment: Cool. I'm seeing the merged tags, but not the merged description? The platformer tag still has the old one-line description and four example games (SMB, DK, CV, LBP).

Comment: Coming back to this meta post later proves to me how increcibly lacking in clarity and attention span this place is. Every answer has been the same conclusion, merge. But it took a user with 4k rep saying it, to trigger enough cognitive bias to start the same loop with upvotes and their bias.